# BarLegend with comma as NumberPoint

Tags: legending, number-representation

I'm having trouble in plotting a Barlegend with comma as decimal separator in *Wolfram Mathematica 13.0*.

I already tried to change the environment variables or to use `SetOptions[FixedPointForm, NumberPoint -> ","]`. It worked fine for other plots except for BarLegend.

I'd like to know if it is a bug or if I'm not doing it in the right way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `SetOptions[NumberForm, NumberPoint->","]`?

Comment: This is a simple solution and it works very well.
It works for BarLegend even if 'Edit>Preferences...>Appearance>Formatting>Numbers>Decimal point character' is set to 'Period'.
Thanks, you helped a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Suggesting a work-around using an undocumented option for [`LabelingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelingFunction.html).

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {1.3, 15.5}}, 12, 
 "LabelingFunction" -> (NumberForm[#, 10, NumberPoint -> ","] &)]
```

> [image: png]

Comment: Your solution also seems to solve the problem.
A better way may be to use `SetOptions[NumberForm, NumberPoint->","]` as pointed by @kglr .

Comment: @J.O.deSarro thanks. Yes, I checked the suggested solution by kglr after having posted mine and it works fine as well :)